# retraction induces short exact sequence of fundamental groups

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups, exact-sequence

Let $(X,x_0)$ be a based retract of $(Y,y_0)$ with retraction $R$ and inclusion $\iota$ such that
$$R\circ\iota=\mathrm{id}_X.$$

> Show that there is a short exact sequence
>   $$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow\pi_1(Y,y_0)\xrightarrow{R_*}\pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow 1,$$
>   where $N:=\ker(R_*)$.

So I thought it suffices to show that $R_*$ is surjective.
We have
$$R_*\circ\iota_*=\mathrm{id}_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}$$
But this already implies that $R_*$ is surjective and since $N=\ker(R_*)$, the above is an exact sequence.

This seems too simple to me, did I miss something?

Comment: No you're not missing anything. I think the point was for you to realize that retractions are "absolutely surjective" : any functor sends them to epimorphisms

Comment: @Max Ok, thank you very much!